# Print factors of number using fencepost loop

Tags: java

I was wondering if this code could be optimized in any way? For instance, could I use a for each loop here? Are there other ways I could write this which would make it easier for me, or the person reading it to understand?

```
public static void printFactors(int factorsOf) {
    for (int i = 1; i < factorsOf; i++) {
        if(factorsOf % i == 0) {
            System.out.print(i + " and ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print(factorsOf);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a print in each loop will be slow. There's too many of them, and print's are inherently slow because they are IO bound, require locks and synchronization, etc.

Additionally, looping for each possible factor is slow too. There are faster ways to identify the factors of a number, that's a whole other discussion though ([Wikipedia has a great page](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Integer_factorization)).

So, without altering your algorithm, I would still make changes.

The first thing I would do is break out a function to compute an int-array of the factors. It would look something like:

```
public static final int[] factors(final int factorsOf) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, factorsOf)
            .filter(f -> factorsOf % f == 0)
            .toArray();
}
```

That's Java 8 streams, but the logic should be relatively clear. Loop from 1 to factorsOf, keep those values which are actual factors, and convert the factors to an array of `int[]`.

That is a single-purpose function, which makes it clear, and reusable.

Now, create a function that converts an integer array to an "and" separated string... something like:

```
public static final String joinInts(int[] values, String joiner) {
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(joiner);
    for (int v : values) {
        sj.add(Integer.toString(v));
    }
    return sj.toString();
}
```

Then, use that all as:

```
    System.out.println(joinInts(factors(100), " and "));
```

Comment: Using streams has any performance benefits?

Answer (score 5):

Just a tiny note:

> In number theory, integer factorization is the decomposition of a composite number into a product of smaller integers.

So a *factorization* of 12 may be

```
6 * 2
```

or

```
3 * 2 * 2
```

but not

```
1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 6 and 12
```

What you did is finding all *divisors* and you should name your method appropriately.

---

As always, a method both computing *and* printing something is rather unusable. You should always compute the result in one method, so that you can later either print it or process it further.

For simple methods like yours it doesn't matter much, but it's good habit.

Answer (score 2):

Once you find that `i` is a factor, you know that `factorsOf / i` is also a factor.  This means that the `for` loop doesn't need to exceed the square root of `factorsOf`.  For example, with 75, you will immediately get complementary factors of 75, 25, and 15 for the early factors of 1, 3, and 5.  There is no point in checking for values of `i` above 9 (slightly higher than `sqrt(75)`).  This will save a great deal of testing for large values of `factorsOf` since 1 through `sqrt(n)` has far fewer elements than `sqrt(n)` through `n`.  If you need all the factors in order, you could store the early factors and their complementary factors in an array and sort it later.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for all factors of the given number this can be done in Sqrt(n). Divisors comes in pair if i divides n then n/i too divides n hens it can be done on sqrt(n) Below is the cpp inplementation.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


vector<int> all_factor(int n){
    vector<int> factor;
    for(int i=1;i<=sqrt(n);i++){
        if(n%i==0){
            factor.push_back(i);//if i divids n so n/i too divids n
            if(n/i!=i)factor.push_back(n/i);
        }
    }
    return factor;
}
int main() {

    vector<int> ans = all_factor(6000);
    sort(ans.begin(),ans.end());
    for(int i=0;i<ans.size();i++)cout << ans[i]<<",";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @rolfl stream bases `factors` implementation but don't like much his `joinInts` method. The both tasks - finding factors and creating text output - may be implemented only with a help of *Stream API* only:

```
public static void printFactors(int factorsOf) {
    String result =
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, factorsOf)
            .filter(f -> factorsOf % f == 0)
            .mapToObj(v -> Integer.toString(v))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" and "));

    System.out.println(result);
}
```